# Changing Chapter Number to have Two Numbers

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am working in the book class, and currently I have

```
\setcounter{chapter}{10}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}
```

Which generates

> Lecture 11

How do I make it say,

> Lecture 11-12

or

> Lecture 11,12

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On what basis the double number should be used?

Comment: do you always want n-(n+1) and the chapter number to increment by 2 so next would be 13-14 or just this as a special case combined chapter?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

A simplistic way, if you are going to manually set the counter is this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}
\makeatletter
\def\thechapter{\@arabic\c@chapter--\the\numexpr\c@chapter+1\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro to Maths}
\end{document}
```

If you are going to turn the lecture notes into something more complicated, you may have to hack the `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` macros, also you will need to re-write code for the `toc`, `figure` and `table captions` and `headings` etc. I would rather stick to the standard way of one lecture one chapter and rather have a front page (hack the `Part` to do the combination).

[image]

Comment: `\c@chapter` is a counter so the `\@arabic` is not necessary. If anything, then `\def\thechapter{\@arabic\c@chapter--\@arabic\numexpr\c@chapter+1}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks you right. I would rather then just leave the `\the`. Probably also better to inc the counter as well at this point. I wasn't sure what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: better to use an en-dash between numbers.

Comment: Why not simply `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{11--12}`?